# Python Requests PUT Timeout (10060)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a command-line Python script that is looping through the rows of a table, using the python-requests library to make PUT requests to an API for each row. The syntax looks like:

```
updateResponse = requests.put(updateRowUrl, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

The process works well for me, but I have a user getting the following error after the process makes several successful calls:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 105, in put
return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 49, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 457, in reques
t
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 569, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 407, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A con
nection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond afte
r a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond'))
```

Judging by the `10060` error message I thought that the connection was timing out, so I suggested that the user add a `timeout=None` argument to the put call, but this doesn't seem to have solved this issue.

Are there any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the server the requests are going to, have you tried attempting to catch the error, waiting and trying again?

Comment: What do you mean by "waiting and trying again" here? Thanks!

Comment: Zenon, do you mind explaining what waiting and trying again means? If the server's slow, isn't it just going to error again?